# Probability of all men rescue from gun shot!

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose a gun have 3 bullet in it, out of 6 bullet spaces.

There are 3 men front of gun man.

Now gun man roll gun bullet randomly and start shoot 3 men (shot 3 times at different person).

=> What is probability of all men **save** ?

=> What is probability of all men **shot** ?

=> What is probability of **at least one** man shot ?

=> What is probability **of at least one** man save ?

Do we need to consider this event as **Dependent** ?

[ Event is considered from popular bollywood film Sholey ]

[Sholey movie scene](https://s2.dmcdn.net/v/OPdEh1RQ_fWWmgC8x/x1080)

.. had calculated all men saved probability as below, not sure is it correct or not,

**All man saved = 1 - (1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2) ~ 0.125**

***UPDATE:***
Not sure why some people giving down vote, any way I don't care, I got answer from @trueblueanil :D  :D

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: On this site, you are expected to show what effort you have made and where you are stuck before appropriate help is given.

Comment: Is the gun re-rolled after every shot ?

Comment: @trueblueanil, no gun not reload, It have 3 bullets out of 6 holes. A treditional gun

Comment: Unless you show some effort, protocol doesn't permit me to answer.

Comment: Had calculated with this, (also question updated), what extra I should add here?
All man saved = 1 - (1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2) ~ 0.125

Comment: Is this a kind of problem we should look at? Guns and killing are not equivalent to throwing a die or choosing 3 persons out of 14 to win a prize.

Comment: @BernardMasse: There are many classical probability problems on Russian roulette, although with the spate of recent gun killings in USA, it appears macabre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all men saved, your computation is obviously incorrect as it will yield a negative probability.

- It is the multiplication law, not the addition law that is needed
- As shots are fired, the probabilities will go on changing depending on what has happened earlier (*dependent*)

For all men saved, $Pr = \frac36\cdot\frac25\cdot\frac14 = \frac1{20} = 5$ %

Seemingly oddly, probability of all men being shot is also the same !

You can try your hand at the other cases

Comment: thank you for reply.
 As it dependent, can we use multiplication rule ? As one of coursera video I saw we can use multiplication rule if events are independent.
Please check screenshot of slide,
https://i.imgur.com/jtVenb6.png

Comment: The video gives the (special)  multiplication rule for independent events, but you will learn later hat there is a *general* multiplication rule when events are dependent,  P(AB) = P(A)*P(B|A) which means P(A)*P(B given A has happened)